# Convert JSON in a format can be read by JSON_VALUE in oracle

Tags: json, oracle, oracle12c

I have JSON data in format -

```json
{"dims":{"ABC":{"dim":"ABC","bins":{"1290":{"bin":"1290","hits":"1","first_date":"03.11.15"},"345":{"bin":"345","hits":"2","first_date":"03.11.15"},"6603":{"bin":"6603","hits":"1","first_date":"23.12.15"},"6609":{"bin":"6609","hits":"1","first_date":"13.12.15"}}}}}
```

How can I convert it into a format -

```json
{"dims":{"BINDUNGS_ID_CARDS":{"dim":"BINDUNGS_ID_CARDS","bins":[{"bin":"1290","hits":"1","first_date":"03.11.15"},{"bin":"345","hits":"2","first_date":"03.11.15"},{"bin":"6603","hits":"1","first_date":"23.12.15"},{"bin":"6609","hits":"1","first_date":"13.12.15"}]}}}
```

I want to read it from oracle using JSON_VALUE function via  `JSON_VALUE(value, $.*.*.bins[0])`.

I have no idea how can i achieve it via oracle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reformat it using:

```sql
SELECT j.*
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY (
         SELECT JSON_OBJECT(
                   'dims' VALUE JSON_OBJECT(
                     'BINDUNGS_ID_CARDS' VALUE JSON_OBJECT(
                       'dims' VALUE 'BINDUNGS_ID_CARDS',
                       'bins' VALUE JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                         data FORMAT JSON ORDER BY ROWNUM
                       )
                     )
                   )
                ) As value
         FROM   JSON_TABLE(
                  t.value,
                  '$.*.*.bins.*'
                  COLUMNS (
                    data CLOB FORMAT JSON PATH '$'
                  )
                )
       ) j
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name ( value CLOB CHECK ( value IS JSON ) );

INSERT INTO table_name ( value )
VALUES (
'{
  "dims":{
    "ABC":{
      "dim":"ABC",
      "bins":{
        "1290":{"bin":"1290","hits":"1","first_date":"03.11.15"},
        "345":{"bin":"345","hits":"2","first_date":"03.11.15"},
        "6603":{"bin":"6603","hits":"1","first_date":"23.12.15"},
        "6609":{"bin":"6609","hits":"1","first_date":"13.12.15"}
      }
    }
  }
}' );
```

Outputs:

> ```
> | VALUE                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       |
> | :-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- |
> | {"dims":{"BINDUNGS_ID_CARDS":{"dims":"BINDUNGS_ID_CARDS","bins":[{"bin":"1290","hits":"1","first_date":"03.11.15"},{"bin":"345","hits":"2","first_date":"03.11.15"},{"bin":"6603","hits":"1","first_date":"23.12.15"},{"bin":"6609","hits":"1","first_date":"13.12.15"}]}}} |
> ```

---

However, this feels like an XY-problem.

> I want to read it from oracle using JSON_VALUE function via `JSON_VALUE(value, $.*.*.bins[0])`.

If you want the first value from the object then you do not need to reformat the JSON and can get it directly using:

```sql
SELECT bin,
       hits,
       TO_DATE( first_date, 'DD.MM.RR' ) AS first_date
FROM   table_name t
       CROSS APPLY JSON_TABLE(
         t.value,
         '$.*.*.bins.*'
         COLUMNS (
           rn         FOR ORDINALITY,
           bin        VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.bin',
           hits       VARCHAR2(20) PATH '$.hits',
           first_date VARCHAR2(8) PATH '$.first_date'
         )
       ) j
WHERE  rn = 1
```

Which outputs:

> ```
> BIN  | HITS | FIRST_DATE         
> :--- | :--- | :------------------
> 1290 | 1    | 2015-11-03 00:00:00
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2754f6eb81590b6168364a58a0a731c6)*